# ¿como definir los puertos en Arduino desde lenguaje ensamblador?

Tags: arduino, ensamblador

Estoy intentando aprender programación de Arduino en ensamblador, usando como placa un Arduino UNO R3 y basándome en los ejemplos de este tutorial:
https://www.cypherpunk.at/2014/09/native-assembler-programming-on-arduino/

He logrado ensamblar y grabar el blink del primer ejemplo, el cual enciende un led conectado al pin 13 de la placa.

Pero me interesaría poder cambiar el pin de salida, para que en vez de usar el pin 13, use otro pin, como por ejemplo el 3.

¿como podría cambiar eso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente lo encontré, en estas dos lineas

```
ldi r16,0x20 ; set port bits to output mode
 out DDRB,r16
```

La primera linea dice el pin a usar, que se define poniendo a 1 su posición. La posición 5 seria 100000, lo cual en hexadecimal es 20, de ahí la primera instrucción. Si quisiera poner la posición 3 pondría 1000, 8 en hexadecimal.

Y el puerto se define con los DDR*, poniendo DDRB, DDRD, o el que corresponda.

Finalmente, la correspondencia entre los pines de la placa y los del microcontrolador esta aquí: https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino_Uno_Rev3-schematic.pdf

Así que, con esos dos datos, ya he podido definir los pines que quiero usar